# Drawing div by using :before and :after selector

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to understand `:before` and `:after` in css.

For that I'm trying to make this div symmetric. The after part works as expected, AFAIK:

```
//            up    left  right  bottom
border-width: 500px 80px  0      0;
```

Then with the `border-color` I simulate the `/`

```
border-color: transparent green transparent transparent;
```

[Check the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yorch/t5147b0k/)

But when I try to put the `before` part and draw a `\`, it does not work

```
//            up    left  right  bottom
border-width: 500px 0     80px   0;
```

Then with the `border-color` I simulate the `/`

```
border-color: transparent transparent green transparent;
```

Complete `:before` I've tried:

```
#liquid:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 500px 0 80px 0;
    border-color: transparent transparent green transparent;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Someone knows how to achieve it? And more important... **WHY**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to make it symmetric, it should be:

```
border-width: 500px 0 0 80px;
border-color: transparent transparent transparent green;
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/edq55ve4/)

```
#liquid:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 500px 0 0 80px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent green;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

You were using the following, which was modifying the `border-bottom` rather than the `border-left`:

```
border-width: 500px 0 80px 0;
border-color: transparent transparent green transparent;
```

Comment: Works like charm... is my reference for border (`up - left - right - bottom`) incorrect? I can't get why setting border to top and bottom draws the line as expected...

Comment: @JordiCastilla It's top, right, bottom, left.. The way I remember it is TRBL.. it spells out the word 'trouble'..

Comment: THAT's THE POINT! thanks a lot! PS: **love the mnemotecnic rule :)**